# Is it possible to run functions asynchronically in Adobe Illustrator scripting?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I have made a script for Adobe Illustrator. But I have a problem: I need some functions to be applied step-by-step (asynchronically). These functions are: prepareToScript, selectTextObjects, mergeTextObjects, moveNamesToNewLayer or leaveNamesOnCurrentLayer. Is it possible to do that? Here is the part of the code:

```
function runThisScript() {

  var doc = app.activeDocument;

    doc.selection = null;
    var layer = doc.activeLayer;

    var layer = doc.layers.getByName("Layer 1");

    doc.activeLayer = layer;

    prepareToScript();
    selectTextObjects();
    mergeTextObjects();

  if (processAllChk.value) {
    processAllNames();
    app.preferences.setStringPreference(allKey, "true");
  }

  if (moveNamesChk.value) {
    moveNamesToNewLayer();
  } else {
    if (!wasTrans) {
        leaveNamesOnCurrentLayer();
    }
    moveNamesToNewLayer();
  }
}
```

I have tried callbacks and awaits. Either I did something wrong or they don't work in Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: You mean you want them to be executed in order, one after the end of the previous one, even though they are asynchronous. This is done by putting async function runThisScript() and inside the function by putting await prepareToScript, await selectTextObjects, .... I have one more remark about the last block of the code. The command moveNamesToNewLayer(); will be executed in any case, so you can simplify it:
if (!wasTrans) {

         leaveNamesOnCurrentLayer();

}

moveNamesToNewLayer();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the classic Extendscript (the legacy Adobe's variant of Javascript, jsx files) the answer is 'No'. It has no async/await functions.

If you mean the new UPX-scripting it's another matter. But, as far as I know UPX doesn't work with Adobe Illustrator for now: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/when-will-adobe-uxp-for-illustrator-be-released/td-p/13473663

If you mean the scripting for CEP panel, there is the modern Javascript but it works only within the CEP interface. As soon as you need to get the access to the graphic inside your document you have to call the classic Extendscript script again with all its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

`await` only works in `async` functions. Try to write `async` before the `function` keyword.